# Do not reload page if unrecognized username or password

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have custom module, which work fine. If login was success user stay in the same page, if login was not success user stay in the same page. Now I want to not reload page, if user login was not success, when unrecognized username or password.

Could someone help me?

Maybe I can add js when page went to `current_path()`:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
```

does not work.

This is my code:

```
function redirect_after_login_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset') {
    if (in_array('authenticated user', $account->roles)) {
      drupal_add_js('http://js.hs-scripts.com/2851839.js', 'external');
      drupal_goto(current_path());
    }
  }
}
function redirect_after_login_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_block':
      $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_login_val';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function my_custom_login_val($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = form_get_error($form['name']) . form_get_error($form['pass']);
  if($form != '') {
    $_GET['destination'] = current_path();
    drupal_goto(current_path());
    drupal_add_js('
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      alert("Hello!");
    });', 'inline');  
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Use AJAX. PHP can't help you here.

Comment: you can use two steps login, this module will not refresh page if incorrect username or password is entered. URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/two_steps_login

Comment: [related](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/246744/20140)